# Add information through a stored procedure and PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form which contains a lot of elements, my DB guy has generated an SP and now i need to call that stored procedure. My form has twenty elements, when i click on submit the data must be saved in database. I know how to do this on insert query, but how to call an SP and perform this operation.

There are 10 tables where the data is going to get saved.

Comment: Just use plain damn SQL. Screw stored procedures.

Comment: There are 10 tables where the data needs insertion.

Comment: Then write 10 plain damn SQL queries, or fix your schema.

Comment: @Coronatus - if I could downvote comments, I would downvote both of yours.  Plain SQL increases the likelihood of SQL injection attacks, and requires additional privileges on tables which in combination with SQL injection can give attackers full access to tables.  It sounds like theband's database is normalised - why does this require "fixing"?  It's good database design.

Comment: By the way, is "plain damn SQL" a dialect of SQL?  I've not heard of it before.

Comment: @Andy Considering 99.999% of SQL queries are not stored procedures, I think your point is moot.

Comment: If your DB guy already wrote the stored procedures, it doesn't matter how many tables the data gets written to, you just have to call the procedure(s) with the correct data and that's it.

Comment: @Coronatus: Where do you base your statistics?  How exactly does it make my point moot?  99.999% of systems I've worked with have used stored procedures to modify data, and views to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never used stored procedures in MySQL, but it's no different from "plain" SQL queries, except you use `CALL` as the query keyword.

Instead of:

```
INSERT INTO table (column1, column2, column3) VALUES ('value 1', 'value 2', 3)
```

you do:

```
CALL function_name('value 1', 'value 2', 3);
```

(this is assuming your stored procedure is called `function_name` and takes 2 string arguments and a numeric argument.

Comment: And of course you can do it using prepared statements as well ie. use CALL function_name(:param1,:param2,:param3) and set the value for the parameters afterwards in your code (for input/output parameters check http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Answer (score 1):

[**PDO**](http://es.php.net/pdo) has a nice way of working with stored procedures through prepared statements. I strongly recommend working with it instead of working with "plain damn SQL".

```
<?php
// Calling a stored procedure with an output parameter
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("CALL sp_returns_string(?)");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $return_value, PDO::PARAM_STR, 4000); 

// call the stored procedure
$stmt->execute();

print "procedure returned $return_value\n";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, i feel this is slightly complex.

Comment: Any reasons to for PDO instead of plain SQL apart from security

Comment: PDO is still using plain SQL - it's exactly the same SQL as you'd pass to mysql_query, for example.  The difference is it's a better coding methodology (it's object-oriented.)  From a security point-of-view it allows you to do parameterised queries so you don't have to worry about escaping all your input, but you can do that with the normal MySQL extension anyway, I believe.

Comment: security is a sufficient enough argument for me.

Answer (score 0):

use CALL see http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-storedproc.html